# Why am I getting an internal server error when uploading files over 10MB?

Tags: php, upload

I'm writing my own little file upload CMS in php for my website.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I upload anything over 13MB or so the upload reaches 100% then instantly greets me with an internal server error page, and the file is not uploaded. Other than that the file uploading works completely perfectly.

For reference, I changed all of these php ini settings and it still doesn't work:

```
max_execution_time = 1200     
max_input_time = 1200   
memory_limit = 120M      
max_file_uploads =120MB  
upload_max_filesize = 120M
post_max_size = 130M
```

and the code I'm using to store my files is after they've been posted is:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/download/".$name);
```

Also my website's running on a virtual server provided by fatcow.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the changes?

Comment: Are you able to see the server's error log? It should help a lot.

Comment: Seeing as its shared hosting, I'm not able to restart the server, maybe I should take it up with the hosting provider though.

Comment: Alright I found my error log, but there's abolutely nothing recent, only errors pertaining to different directories and different problems I had in the past ):

Comment: Alright, I'm off to bed. If there are no super dandy answers by tomorrow I'll start down the treacherous path of fatcow user support. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got an answer, but its not a good one.

Apparently, although it says nowhere on their site, the max file upload size on their server is 10MB, no matter what you change in the php ini or otherwise. I had to go through live chat and all that jazz to learn this, and it sucks.

So a word to the wise, if you want decently sized user upload, don't host with fatcow.

Comment: That is a pretty common limit for any shared hosting. If you need to upload larger files you'll need to go with a desicated server or a vps.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue when PHP is running as a fcgid handler. If you have changed the settings in `php.ini` and restarted the server to no avail, you need to set [FcgidMaxRequestLen](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) in your `http.conf`.

The value is in bytes. I would just set it to a large enough value to accomodate the largest POST value you are expecting:

```
#Max request size of 13 megabytes
FcgidMaxRequestLen 13631488
```